# UILabels don't look good in the landcsape mode

Tags: iphone

I am writing a game in the landscape mode. In *.plist I've set the "Initial interface orientation" option to "Landscape (left home button)". In Interface Builder my form seems good, with 2 labels are on the left and bottom.
But when I launch the app in simulator or in iphone that looks like the following

http://www.glowfoto.com/static_image/07-102041L/8907/png/09/2010/img4/glowfoto

Labels are on the top and rotated. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your view controller's shouldAutorotateToOrientation method is not returning YES to landscape but to portrait orientations. But without code it's a guess in the wild.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have added the code into my UIViewController class  -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

Comment: To make your app two start better, also allow UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight. It's really annoying forcing the user to use only one of them. ;-)